# Controlling the SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm having a problem with the ASP.NET version of the ReportViewer control for SSRS.

In my ASP.NET web forms file I have:

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="webViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" 
        ProcessingMode="Remote">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="/AnalyticReports/SiteOverview" 
            ReportServerUrl="http://someserver/ssrs" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

This works fine and dandy as expected.

However, say I want to change the server and report path programmatically. How would I do that?

I tried this:

```
webViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://someserver/ssrs");
webViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/AnalyticReports/SiteOverview";
webViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

However that doesn't seem to do anything. I even tried adding a webViewer.Reset() but to no avail.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show us the rest of the code; perhaps the issue is elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it seems that the problem lies with the `Page_Load` event. After coming across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx I tried `Page_Init` and things seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

i did this using a property which will get and set the values

```
public string ReportPathString 
{ get { return ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath; } 
  set { ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = value; } 
}

public string ReportServerUrlString 
{ get { return ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl.ToString(); } 
  set { ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(value); } 
}
```

also while at page_load, i use the following code for setting the credentials

```
IReportServerCredentials irsc = new ReportServerCredentials("Username", "Password", "Domain");
```

the class that is use like below

```
public class ReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
private string _UserName;
private string _PassWord;
private string _DomainName;

public ReportServerCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
{
    _UserName = UserName;
    _PassWord = PassWord;
    _DomainName = DomainName;
}

public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
{
    // use default identity
    get { return null; }
}

public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
{
    // use default identity
    get { return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, _DomainName); }
}

public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user,
 out string password, out string authority)
{
    authCookie = null;
    user = password = authority = null;
    return false;
}


}
```

EDIT: just saw the topic is a year old ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, Lloyd?

```
webViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
```

Comment: Yes I've tried that. Currently its in the control markup but I've also tried explicitly setting it.

Comment: Have you verified the connection string(s) and permissions are all good on the remote server? Is the report viewer immediately returning blank or timing out?

Comment: Yes. Like I said it works with the settings hard coded in the markup, the report runs fine comes back etc.

Comment: silly question-- but are you sure the statements where you are setting the values for the ReportServer are getting set? Where are those statements?

Comment: In the Page_Load event of the aspx page. I'm pretty sure they're getting set.

Answer (score 0):

I use LocalReport which seemed to work better:

```
var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", resultSet);

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("/Reports/" + reportName + ".rdl");
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Local reports aren't possible for us in this case :(

Comment: In my case, they are "local" to the server. We still use the web viewer and the user does not see any difference.